# Splitting large data set into columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a large data set that I have managed to arrange in the following format as an example:

```
A       A
One     1
Two     2
Three   3
Four    4
Five    5
Six     6
Seven   7
B       B
One     1
Two     2
Three   3
Four    4
Five    5
Six     6
C       C
One     1
Two     2
Three   3
Four    4
Five    5
Six     6
Seven   7
Eight   8
```

I would like to split the data into separate columns...like this:

```
A       A   B       B   C       C
One     1   One     1   One     1
Two     2   Two     2   Two     2
Three   3   Three   3   Three   3
Four    4   Four    4   Four    4
Five    5   Five    5   Five    5
Six     6   Six     6   Six     6
Seven   7               Seven   7
                        Eight   8
```

This is one of the last steps in getting my data into a usable format. I am already employing various VBA macros to get the data into the first format. I hit a roadblock with this next major step. I have done some extensive googling and have not been able to come with the right macro. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is it the values in column A and B being the same that indicates the start of a new section?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The values being the same indicates a new column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no other frills and you're headers being more than just `A`, `B`, or `C`, I'd use the following macro. Just to be clear, this is highly inflexible. It will only work if you've got exactly the same setup as above, so it's up to you to apply the logic I used and modify it to suit your needs.

```
Sub NoFrills()

    Dim aRng As Range, bRng As Range, cRng As Range
    Dim endA As Long, endB As Long, endC As Long
    Dim aRngToCopy As Range, bRngToCopy As Range, cRngToCopy As Range
    Dim NextCol As Long, RngToCopy As Range

    Set aRng = Columns(1).Find(What:="Alpha")
    Set bRng = Columns(1).Find(What:="Beta")
    Set cRng = Columns(1).Find(What:="Charlie")

    'endA = bRng.Offset(-1, 0).Row 'Not really needed.
    endB = cRng.Offset(-1, 0).Row
    endC = cRng.End(xlDown).Row

    'Set aRngToCopy = Range(aRng, Cells(endA, 2)) 'Not really needed.
    Set bRngToCopy = Range(bRng, Cells(endB, 2))
    Set cRngToCopy = Range(cRng, Cells(endC, 2))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    NextCol = aRng.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Column
    bRngToCopy.Cut Cells(1, NextCol)

    NextCol = aRng.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Column
    cRngToCopy.Cut Cells(1, NextCol)

    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

My approach here is to determine ahead of time all the "blocks" of cells needing to be cut and transferred into the horizontal format. Then, I keep on determining the next column that needs to be targeted by calling `NextCol` again and again and pasting to that cell.

The logic, of course, is that you've got more ranges, you have to store these ranges somewhere (hint, hint) and loop over them (more hint, hint).

Let us know if this helps or at the very least points you in the direction you want.

**Screenshots:**

Set-up:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I think it does point me in the right direction. I think my problem is that the dataset is large and the list of new columns required can sometimes be around 75, with variability in the header name (But always text). I wonder if I could convert the headers to a string that could easily be recognized.

Comment: @Clinpath: By your comment, it seems that all data beneath the headers are purely numbers. Is this what you are implying? If this is the case, I'd go `RegEx` and determine the headers ahead of time, store them in an array or collection, then make a massive loop of the above, iterating over each array/collection element and creating ranges to cut and paste them. Is this correct?